# JAX-WS SOAP and/or JAX-RS REST Android, the data didn't appear on my apps

Tags: android, web-services, rest, soap, jax-ws

My projection is to build a web service that can be read on my Android apps and any web framework like CodeIgniter or YII, but I want it to be implemented on Android first.
I'd already try to figure out what I need, but I just can get a few source, because I don't have any experience in this.

I tried to learn between REST and SOAP,

**REST** :
I choose the REST first, and I try this [tutorial](http://avilyne.com/?p=105), but I have a problem with the webservice that I build both on Eclipse and Netbeans IDE, and this is what happen when I run my webservice on my tomcat server, Tomcat failed to start and appear like this on the console. (actually, I'd already post the problem on that tutorial page, but the author is not answering my question yet).

```
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10\;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\;C:\Server\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\bin;;D:\Progima\Eclipse JEE Indigo\eclipse;;.
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property ‘source’ to ‘org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Luna’ did not find a matching property.
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 612 ms
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 21, 2012 7:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.sound.AbstractPlayer cannot access its superclass com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1591)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1956)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1919)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1806)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1765)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1751)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1255)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

But when I try to right click the Tomcat server on Eclipse >> General >> Switch Location, then run again, the Tomcat is can started.
The tomcat is started, but when I run localhost:8080[slash]RestWebServiceDemo[slash]rest[slash]person (based on this [tutorial](http://avilyne.com/?p=105)) it still error 404. I don't know what happen.

**SOAP**:Then, I want to try the other solution beside REST. I found this [tutorial](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html), and I'd already try it, I build the web service on both side, Eclipse and Netbeans. In Eclipse, the same thing like I describe above happen again when I try to start server. On Netbeans, the webservice is run normally, and I can start it normally, and I can run the wsdl localhost:9090[slash]Ladodi[slash]Hello?wsdl. But, when I try to get it from my Android, the data is didn't appear on my TextView.

The code on my Netbeans is look like this. I build two operations, with and without parameter, because on the tutorial, the operation is without parameter, and of course I need the parameter on my operations later.

```
package love.care;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 *
 * @author Setyadi
 */
@WebService()
public class Hello {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Hai")
    public String Hai(@WebParam(name = "nama")
    String nama) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        return "Hai";
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Kerupuk")
    public String Kerupuk() {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        return "Cocote";
    }

}
```

and here is the android code on my Eclipse to get "Kerupuk" operation (without parameter).

```
package in.figure.on.mobile;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebServiceActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://care.love/";
    private static String URL = "http://localhost:9090/Ladodi/Hello?wsdl"; 
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Kerupuk";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://care.love/Kerupuk";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);  

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
         ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            TextView helloTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHello);
            helloTV.setText("Asaa :"+response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the android code on my Eclipse to get "Hai" operation (with parameter) and I want to pass "AdityaSetyadi" as parameter.

```
package in.figure.on.mobile;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebServiceActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://care.love/";
    private static String URL = "http://localhost:9090/Ladodi/Hello?wsdl"; 
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Hai";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://care.love/Hai";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);  

          PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();
          propInfo.setName("nama");
          propInfo.setValue("AdityaSetyadi");
          propInfo.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
          request.addProperty(propInfo);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
         ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            TextView helloTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHello);
            helloTV.setText("Asaa :"+response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The different between the two is on PropertyInfo. I try to pass the parameter with addProperty, I try the the code from this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html), but when try to code like this. 
but the addProperty is deprecated, so I try to code above.

```
        PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.name="arg0";
        propInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;

        request.addProperty(propInfo, "John Smith");
```

**But** the data is still not appear on my TextView, I don't know what to do.
Does anybody can help? Or give me another tutorial.
Thanks in advance,
best Regards, @AdityaSetyadi

:'(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this `SoapObject respone = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;`
instead of this line

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

and If you want to add parameter there is alternate way

```
request.addProperty("parameter",value);
```

instead of `PropertyInfo`

and other important things may be you did it all

1) add use internet permission into your project's manifest file

2) Please check `NAMESPACE`,`SOAP_ACTION` are written correctly according to your `Webservice`.
You can verify it by opening `webservice` in browser.There is `NAMESPACE`,`SOAP_ACTION` both are mention.

If you have any doubt then feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I'd already do about internet permission on manifest or NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, etc, thanks. But, can you explain the different between SoapObject and SoapPrimitive please?

Comment: I'd already solve this problem, it's all because the URL, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your web service is a JAX-WS and not .NET then i suggest you replace `envelope.dotNet = true;` with `envelope.dotNet = false;`